# Linq to Entities Groupby Dayname Cumulative Average of Each Days

Tags: c#, linq, date, asp.net-mvc-5, linq-to-entities

I have DB records of daily shopping amounts.
Sample records are below:

> 14.12.2015 11:00 --- 750,00
>
> 14.12.2015 14:35 --- 295,00
>
> .....There are thousands of 14.12.2015
>
> 15.12.2015 17:45 --- 650,00
>
> 15.12.2015 18:46 --- 395,00
>
> ....There are thousands of 15.12 and following days until
>
> 24.12.2015 12:38 --- 675,00
> ...

This means I have records for 11 days 14-24 December. I want to group records by dayname. So I user Linq to Entities command and got the results as I wanted.

```
     var dailyList = await db.ShoppingData.Where(c=>StoreId == id)
.Groupby(c=> SqlFunctions.DatePart("dw",c.ShoppindDate))
.Select(o=> new ShowShoppingDailyVM{
    Day = o.Key,
    Turnover = o.DefaultIfEmpty().Sum(a=>a.InvoiceAmount),//Total Turnover
    Avg= o.DefaultIfEmpty().Sum(a=>a.InvoiceAmount) / (What??) //Avg turnover
    Count = o.Count()
    }).ToListAsync();
```

This gives me

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 as days,
>
> 1200, 1450, 960... as Count
>
> 12.500, 17.650, 18.950... as Turnovers

In these 11 days, I have 2 Monday, 2 Tuesday, 2 Wednesday and 2 Thursday (1 Friday,1 Saturday,1 Sunday).
I need something that will give me the average turnover of Monday. When I use Average method, it divides monday turnover to monday count (In fact CartAverage).
But I actually need to get Monday Turnover / Monday Count (2 Mondays not 1200 transactions)

How can I get the cumulative average of daily amount?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
var dailyList = await db.ShoppingData.Where(c=>StoreId == id)
    .GroupBy(c=> SqlFunctions.DatePart("dw",c.ShoppindDate))
    .Select(o=> new ShowShoppingDailyVM
                  {
                      Day = o.Key,
                      Turnover = o.DefaultIfEmpty().Sum(a=>a.InvoiceAmount),
                      Avg = o.DefaultIfEmpty().Sum(a=>a.InvoiceAmount)
                               /o.Select(d => d.ShoppindDate).Distinct().Count()
                      Count = o.Count()
                  })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Distinct().Count() also returns the same as o.Count(). Because Grouped Date already means Distinct date. It is totally same.

Comment: Of course. o.Count() = 1200, because o groups date 14.12.2015 and there are 1200 records on that day. Distinct().Count() = 1200 because there are 1200 records on 14.12.2015. They are same things.

Comment: I think, I need something to group weekdays or group by week then day. I need to divide total turnover of Monday to Monday count. How many Monday I have on that list. I have 2 Mondays. So I need to divide by 2

Comment: You didn't answer to my question. Have you tried the solution? `o.Distinct().Count()` is different than `o.Select(d => d.ShoppindDate).Distinct().Count()`  **because o groups date 14.12.2015** You haven't grouped by date you have grouped by week day.

Comment: I said "Of course" :) It was the first thing that I've tried before asking that question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved it. I grouped again the "grouped day" by week and I divided the days total turnover to days Weeknumber count.

Below is the working code:

```
     var dailyList = await db.ShoppingData.Where(c=>StoreId == id)
    .Groupby(c=> SqlFunctions.DatePart("dw",c.ShoppindDate))
    .Select(o=> new ShowShoppingDailyVM{
        Day = o.Key,
        Turnover = o.DefaultIfEmpty().Sum(a=>a.InvoiceAmount),//Total Turnover
        //Avg= o.DefaultIfEmpty().Sum(a=>a.InvoiceAmount) / (What??) //Avg turnover
       Avg = o.DefaultIfEmpty().Sum(a=>a.InvoiceAmount) / (decimal) o.GroupBy(a=>
       SqlFunctions.DatePart("week",c.ShoppindDate)).Count(),
        Count = o.Count()
        }).ToListAsync();
```

This was exactly what I needed. Group by day, then group by week inside the grouped days date. 14.12.2015s and 21.12.2015s gives me the Monday for day and 2 for week count. (51. and 52. week of the year)